# Was the name "William the Conqueror" (or its translation) actually used in William's lifetime?

Tags: middle-ages, england, royalty

More generally, what early records do we have of his name?  Who called him "William the Bastard" (French *Guillaume le Bâtard*) - was this mostly his Anglo-Saxon enemies?

Comment: Not literally because it would be in Latin and French. Have you done some research?

Comment: He was called 'the Bastard' by contemporaries; 'the Conqueror' came later,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://www.historyextra.com/period/norman/10-surprising-facts-about-william-the-conqueror-and-the-norman-conquest/

> No one at the time called William ‘the Conqueror’ The earliest
>   recorded use of that nickname occurs in the 1120s, and it didn’t
>   really take off until the 13th century. At the time of his death in
>   1087, William was called ‘the Great’ by his admirers, and ‘the
>   Bastard’ by his detractors.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the second part of your question: William is indeed called "bastardus" in contemporary sources. However, this refers to the fact that his parents were not married. "Bastard" is not used as a term of abuse until the 19th century.

Comment: Minor quibble: "*Bastard*" is attested as a term of derogation by the mid-16th century by the OED, in various forms in 1549, 1552, and others.

Answer (score 4):

Bayeux Tapestry which was commissioned by his close associates (either wife or his half-brother, according to various theories) during his life time calls him Willelm, Wilgelm Normanno Duc, Willem Duc, etc., but never the "Conqueror".